# Mouse wheel click & jquery.delegate

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I would like to understand why the following code does not work when I click with the **mouse wheel**.

```
$(document).delegate("a", "click", function(e) { alert("click"); });
```

This works though (mouse wheel click):

```
$("a").click(function(e) { alert("click"); });
```

Thanks.

edit: 
According to a comment: it's working in IE8, not in Chrome or FF.
Since it works without .delegate, I was thinking it's a jquery problem, but not sure...

Comment: Can you undelete your answer 3nigma and just edit it so that we dont lose the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('body').delegate("a", "click", function(e) { alert("click"); });
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

it should be one thing delegate another to do something.

Comment: Whether it's the body or document that delegates the click event to the links doesn't matter.

Comment: reference some thing on `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.body` and `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document`

Comment: Ok, let's say I use your code, it still doesn't work ;) http://jsfiddle.net/6cVZX/

Comment: @Robin, I have tested in ie, chrome and opera, they all works well, see image `http://i42.tinypic.com/11w7j1s.jpg` do not test google in a frame.

Comment: Some comments on a deleted answer were confirming that it wasn't working for them too. Are you sure that you are clicking the link with your mouse wheel?

Comment: @Robin, ok, if you want use mousewheel for click, you can use `mouseup` or `mousedown` to replace `click` thing, this will open the link in a new window. `$('body').delegate("a", "mouseup", function() { alert("Yeah!") });` or if you do not want open in a new window, why not just use `click`?  `$('a').click(function(){alert("Yeah!");});`

Comment: I already have a working solution using mouseup, but thanks for the tip. I just wanted to know why it wasn't working, because I dont want to have to handle mouse wheel clicks a different way (with mouseup).